# Detecting Flash with Modernizr

Tags: javascript, flash, modernizr

I'm trying to use Modernizr to detect Flash, I've installed Modernizr and the 'flash' class is correctly added to the html tag when installed but I'd like to execute some JavaScript when Flash is detected. I hoped that I could do:

```
if (Modernizr.flash) { ...
```

However this simply returns undefined. Using a similar approach to test audio capability works as expected:

```
if (Modernizr.audio) { ...
```

Returns:

m4a: "maybe"
mp3: "probably"
ogg: "probably"
opus: "probably"
wav: "probably"
...

Where am I going wrong? Have I misunderstood how to address the Flash object in Modernizr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modernizr.flash is an async detect - meaning that it is not necessarily ready until a few cycles after it starts. You can use `Modernzr.on` as a way to wait until the flash detect has completed.

Comment: So would I use something like if(Modernizr.on) { ... } or is it not that simple... I tried and got undefined still...

Comment: no - Modernizr.on is a function that you give a callback to to be alerted once the tests completes - https://github.com/modernizr/modernizr/#new-asynchronous-event-listeners